# Convert javascript to jquery on event handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have the following code:

```
    input.setOnkeypress("if (event.keyCode == 13) 
                {
                document.getElementById('search_report_form:search_button').onclick(); 
                return true;
                }");
```

And this is the function:

```
final class GroupsSelector extends BaseRenderablePanel<GroupsSelector> {
        private GroupsSelector group(LabourInputReportCriteria.Level level) {
            HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox box = new HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox();
            boolean isSelected = selections.isGroupSelected(level);
            box.setSelected(isSelected);
            // box.setDisabled(isDaySelectedOnFirst(level));
            box.setId("groupBy" + level.getClass().getSimpleName());
            box.setOnclick("submit()");
            box.addValueChangeListener(u.addExpressionValueChangeListener("#{reportSearchCriteriaModel.groupBy}"));
            HtmlOutputText labelComponent = new HtmlOutputText();

            labelComponent.setValue(getGroupSelectionValue(level));
            tr().td();
            html(box);
            html("&nbsp;");
            html(labelComponent);
            endTd().endTr();
            return this;
        }
```

Comment: That doesn't look much like javascript...

Comment: So, basically, "please write this for me." I'm afraid that's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Show your html script also

Comment: @freedomn-m: There are five lines of JavaScript buried in there. Six, if you want to count the `submit()` in `box.setOnclick("submit()")`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and this? `final class GroupsSelector extends BaseRenderablePanel<GroupsSelector>` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m: Right, it's some other language (I'd say Java but I don't think the first block is valid Java) that's being used to *generate* HTML and JavaScript. Hence "buried."

Comment: I basically want to change this line document.getElementById('search_report_form:search_button').onclick(); to jquery. Can you please help me?

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana: Just read the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It'll take an hour, two tops, and you'll be able to do this and also your next task, and the one after that. You could be 20 minutes into it already (and quite possibly already have found your answer) if you'd started there.

Comment: @guradio More like $('#search_report_form:search_button') at first glance

Comment: Thank you. I will try the same.

Comment: Okay. I will read it for sure. Thank you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder $('#search_report_form:search_button').trigger("click") ? I'm not sure it will trigger onclick lexically defined on dom tho.

Comment: @StrandedKid: It's the colon that's the issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ha yeah '#search_report_form:search_button' won't return the element indeed, did not pay attention to the :

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana mind if I change the title to match the problem+answer?  will make it more useful to SO and maybe cancel the close votes.

Comment: @ freedomn-m : Okay sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you don't *need* to change it to jQuery if it's working. Adding jQuery to your page doesn't mean the DOM stops working. And if it's *not* working, changing your DOM code to equivalent jQuery code won't make it *start* working.

But the jQuery equivalent of

```
document.getElementById('search_report_form:search_button').onclick();
```

is

```
$('#search_report_form\\3a search_button').click();
```

or more readably;

```
$('[id="search_report_form:search_button"]').click();
```

The tricky bit here is that you have a colon (`:`) in the `id`, so we can't just do `#search_report_form:search_button` to look it up, because the colon looks like it's the beginning of a pseudo-class. So we have to escape it. In CSS selectors, you escape it by replacing it with a backslash followed by its hex equivalent. The character code for `:` in hex is 3A, so `\3a`. To write a backslash in a string literal, you have to write *two* of them (the first escapes the second). You need the space after it to terminate it, hence `'#search_report_form\\3a search_button'`.

The second form uses an attribute selector instead, since we can put the ID in quotes, and don't have to worry about the colon.

Comment: because you are missing id selector `#` @Teemu

Comment: @teemu I'm not sure the element he clicked on is on a form.

Comment: Actually if i use JavaScript, my page is refreshing everytime click on a check box and I dont want that to happen. And hence, I thought of changing it to jquery.

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana: Changing the API you're using won't magically change the logic of your code. If you're having an issue with your page refreshing when you don't want it to, post a question saying that and showing an [MCVE](/help/mcve). Not a question asking to translate something from the DOM API to the jQuery API.

Comment: excellent explanation @T.J.Crowder. to be honest i didnt know it mattered now i learned something

Comment: I am really sorry about it. I thought of giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your first few lines to JQuery then Try this

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
       $('[id="search_report_form:search_button"]').click(); //.submit();
       return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: missed `# ` from `$('search_report_form:search_button')` and fyi downvote not from me

Comment: yes, Above code is not clear like which type of selector will be, so I gave just a sample

Comment: The id is `search_report_form:search_button` - your selector finds a html element `<search_button>` inside an element with id 'search_report_form' - eg `<div id="search_report_form"><search_button/></div>`  - this seems unlikely.

Comment: And *now* it looks for an `id=search_report` element with the pseudo-class `:search_button`. Also unlikely.